# Unable to extract attachment from Multipart input payload and stream it

Tags: java, java-8, streaming, attachment, multipart

I am having a use case, in which my java code is accepting an input payload which in Multipart. I have to extract the attachment from it which could be of size 2GB.
Since the file is very big, I have to accept it as a stream and write it out as a stream.
I have written a code which is working for small files but for big files it is failing, which means streaming is not happening, Could you please help identify why streaming is not working. Thanks in advance.

Below is the Multipart input I will receive

```
multipart/related; boundary="boundary123"
--boundary123
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns:getUserDetailsResponse xmlns:ns="http://example.com">
      <ns:return>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <age>42</age>
      </ns:return>
    </ns:getUserDetailsResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
--boundary123
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="output.txt"

YWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWF==
--boundary123--
```

The output I expect

```
YWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWF==
```

This is the code I have written to read input stream, extract attachment and write as a output stream

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PipedInputStream;
import java.io.PipedOutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class AttachmentExtractor {
    public static InputStream extract(String message, int bufferSize) throws IOException, MessagingException {

        InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        PipedOutputStream attachmentOutStream = new PipedOutputStream();
        PipedInputStream pipedStream = new PipedInputStream(attachmentOutStream);
        
        Thread newThread = new Thread(() -> {
            
        //  int chunkCount = 1 ;    /* only used for testing */
            
            int bytesRead;
            String boundary = null;
            boolean isFirstChunk = true;
            boolean isLastChunk = false;
            
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            
            try {
                
                if(input.available() < 3 * bufferSize)
                    buffer = new byte[input.available()];
                
                while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    
                    // System.out.println("Chunk #"+chunkCount);  /* only used for testing */

                    if(isFirstChunk) {
                        
                        String firstChunk = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        
                        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("boundary=\"(.*)\"");
                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(firstChunk);
                        if (matcher.find()) {
                            boundary = matcher.group(1);
                        } else {
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to extract boundary from input stream.");
                        }

                        DataSource bufferDS = new ByteArrayDataSource(firstChunk.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "multipart/form-data");  
                        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart(bufferDS);
                        int attachmentPartIndex = multipart.getCount() - 1;
                        MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = (MimeBodyPart) multipart.getBodyPart(attachmentPartIndex);

                        attachmentPart.getDataHandler().writeTo(attachmentOutStream);

                        isFirstChunk = false;
                        
                    }else if (isLastChunk) {
                        
                        InputStream bufferIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bufferIS));
                        String line;
                        while(reader.ready() && (line=reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            
                            if(line.indexOf(boundary)>0)
                                continue;
                            
                            attachmentOutStream.write(line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                        }
                        
                    }else
                        attachmentOutStream.write(buffer);
                    
                    if(input.available() <= bufferSize)
                        isLastChunk = true;
                    
                    // chunkCount++;  /* only used for testing */
                }
                
                try {
                    attachmentOutStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) { /* Output Stream already closed - can be ignored. */ }
                
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        
        newThread.start();

        return pipedStream;        

    }
}
```

Here streaming is not happening as it only works for small files and gives Heap Space error once I send a big file.

**Please note I can only use Java 8**